# How can I determine if a table exists in the current search_path with PLPGSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, catalogs

I'm writing a setup script for an application that's an addon for another application, so I want to check if the tables for the other application exist.  If not, I want to give the user a useful error.  However, I don't know what schema will be holding the tables.

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM 1
    FROM
        pg_catalog.pg_class c
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    WHERE
        n.nspname = current_setting('search_path')
        AND c.relname = 'foo'
        AND c.relkind = 'r'; -- not sure if I actually need this or not...

    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RAISE 'This application depends on tables created by another application';
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

However, `current_setting('search_path')` returns a TEXT containing `"$user",public` by default, which isn't terribly useful.

The only other thing I can think of is to try selecting from the table and catch the exception.  It would do the job, but I don't think it is very elegant and I've read that it is *expensive* to use (though maybe that would be ok in this scenario since I'm only running it once?).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Quick (and dirty?)

In Postgres **9.4 or newer** use [`to_regclass()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE):

```
SELECT to_regclass('foo');
```

Returns NULL if there is no relation of that name in the search path.

In Postgres **9.3 or older** (or any version) use a [cast to `regclass`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860):

```
SELECT 'foo'::regclass;
```

This ***raises an exception***, if the object is not found!

See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860)

If `'foo'` is found, the `oid` is returned - which is represented as text. That's the relation name, schema-qualified according to the current search path and double-quoted where necessary.

If the relation is not found you can be *sure* it does not exist anywhere in the search path - or not at all for a schema-qualified name (`schema.foo`).

If it's found there are two **shortcomings**:

1. The search includes implicit schemas of the [search_path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860), namely ***`pg_catalog` and `pg_temp`***. But you may want to exclude temp and system tables for your purpose. (?)
2. A cast to `regclass` finds any relation (table-like object) in the system catalog [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html): table, index, view, sequence etc. ***Not just a regular table.*** Other objects of the same name might produce a false positive.

#### Slow and sure (still fast, really)

We are back to something like your query. But don't use <strike>`current_setting('search_path')`</strike>, which returns the bare setting. Use the dedicated system information function [**`current_schemas()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE). The manual:

> `current_schemas(boolean)` `name[]`
> names of schemas in search path, optionally including implicit schemas

`"$user"` in the `search_path` is resolved smartly. If no schema with the name of the current `SESSION_USER` exists, it resolves to nothing. You can additionally output implicit schemas (`pg_catalog` and possibly `pg_temp`) - but I assume not for the case at hand, so:

```
DO 
$do$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (
      SELECT  -- list can be empty
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
      JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE  n.nspname = ANY(current_schemas(FALSE))
      AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'  -- exclude system schemas!
      AND    c.relname = 'foo'
      AND    c.relkind = 'r')           -- you probably need this
   THEN
      RAISE 'This application depends on tables created by another application';
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=95e58669900ad870410eea4736c319ad)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e23e1/27)</sub>

Comment: May I know why is `SELECT to_regclass('foo');` considered to be _dirty_?

Comment: @tukusejssirs: Because of the *shortcommings* I mentioned at the bottom of the paragraph.

Comment: fwiw, to include a schema: `SELECT to_regclass('schema.tablename');`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the config value to an array and replace the `$user` with the current user name. The array can then be used in the where condition:

```
where n.nspname = any(string_to_array(replace(current_setting('search_path'), '$user', current_user), ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
./sshi.sh vb20deployment controller <<'HERE'
export PGPASSWORD="postgres"
cd logu/postgresql/bin
row=1
tableArray=(table1 table2 table3 table4 table5 table6)

for (( x=0 ; x<=5 ; x++)) ; do        

./psql.bin --port=5432 --username=postgres --host=hostname.rds.amazonaws.com --dbname=mydb -c "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE '${tableArray[$x]}' = table_name" | while read -a Record ; do
  row=$((row + 1))
  if [[ $row -gt 3 ]]; then

     echo ${Record[4]}

   fi
done

done


HERE
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you'll need this functionality a lot, there probably is a sense to create a function which will do the check. Something like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS table_exists(table_name varchar);
CREATE FUNCTION table_exists(table_name varchar) RETURNS bool AS $$
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I LIMIT 0', table_name);
        RETURN true;
    EXCEPTION WHEN undefined_table THEN
        RETURN false;
    END;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And than you can use it like this:

```
SELECT table_exists('my_table_name')
```

Or in pgPL/SQL:

```
IF table_exists('my_table_name') THEN ...
```

Comment: This is open to SQL injection. Don't concatenate object names in a dynamic SQL string without proper quoting. Use `%L` instead of `%s` here. Also, the function may return `false` and a table of the given name may still exist, just outside the current `search_path`. So "table_exists" seems misleading. Maybe "table_exists_in_current_search_path"? Finally, a function with an `EXCEPTION` clause is considerably more expensive than the query of the OP.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Good point about SQL injection, thanks, I've update the code (though, it doesn't work with `%L`, had to change to `%I`).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter regarning exception (just asking) — is it considered to avoid exceptions in Postres PL/SQL? I have some background on semi-professional development in Oracle PL/SQL — and there exceptions were used as ordinary part of logic.

Comment: Yes, `%I` (identifier), not `%L` (literal), sorry. Yes, use an `EXCEPTION` clause to trap errors in PL/pgSQL. (Not "PL/SQL", the name is different fro the Oracle procedural language.) But only if you have to. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233394/3684. If you use this function (which I wouldn't, honestly), consider a cheaper `LIMIT 0` instead of `LIMIT 1`. And be aware, that you might find a view or sequence instead of a table ...