# Does the "don't use errors for flow control" axiom apply to postgres?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, error-handling, condition

In traditional programming there is an axiom that states, "do not use errors for flow control". A general example is to throw an error then catch the error instead of using an ordinary conditional statement or break statement. This is harmful because the application has to unwind the call stack and invoke some relatively expensive exception handling logic versus simply handling a conditional statement.

I am working with a Postgres system where a user is calling a function in Postgres that throws an error instead of returning no rows when a condition is not met. The condition is roughly a "this input value does not exist, nothing to do" as opposed to a truly exceptional case.

Does Postgres incur runtime costs when an error is thrown in a similar manner traditional programming? In other words is using exceptions as flow control in Postgres harmful to performance or just sloppy?

Comment: I assume you refer to [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) functions? And I assume, by "stored procedures" you mean "functions"? (But the same happens to apply to actual stored [procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) as well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't tell, from the top of my head, the exact sequence of events in case of an exception. But I can tell you that it is comparatively ***expensive*** and should be avoided unless needed. An exception (error) causes the surrounding transaction to be rolled back, unless trapped.

But to trap an error, you need an `EXCEPTION` clause in a [plpgsql block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) (in a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html), [procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) or a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement). And it is expensive to have an `EXCEPTION` clause in a plpgsql function block to begin with (even if no exceptions are raised), because such a block effectively forms a subtransaction (that can potentially be rolled back) incurring substantially more overhead. Consequently, [the manual warns:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

> A block containing an `EXCEPTION` clause is significantly more expensive to enter and exit than a block without one. Therefore, don't use `EXCEPTION` without need.